# MATE drawer config

Tags: mate, panel

I have a number of panel drawers on a Ubuntu MATE system (20.04.5 LTS) which contain a number of application launchers with fairly complex command arguments. I have another system running MATE (22.04.1 LTS) and would like to duplicate these drawers from the former system onto the latter. Are there config files or trees for MATE drawers which can be copied and installed elsewhere to duplicate their functionality on another system? All the icons and apps will be on the new system. What's basically needed is the drawer structure and the full commands for each app referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got a new computer and wanted to copy a panel to it. After a lot of digging around, I decided it was easier to recreate it by hand than try to copy it. But here's what I found.

First, you may be directed to the [Mate Tweak tool](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-tweak). With it, you can save and later restore panels. But it stores these configurations in the `dconf` database. They are not easily accessed, which I'll discuss later.

Mate stores its panels' layout in the `dconf` database and its launchers in `~/.config/mate/panel2.d/*/launchers/`, one directory for each layout. You'll need both to copy a drawer.

The `dconf` database can be access via the `dconf` command:

```
dconf dump /org/mate/panel/
```

This will dump the layout for all panels.

It may be possible to copy and load on another system via the `dconf compile` command but I don't know the format of the files involved.

Hope this helps.